# HTML5 video 'object-fit' altarnative in CSS

Tags: safari, html5-video

I'm using background video in my webpage, so what could be alternative way of css attribute `object-fit` for full-sized html5 video?

I see it's not supported in many browsers: http://caniuse.com/object-fit.

Comment: Annoyingly this still hasn't been added to `<video>` elements in Edge despite being added to `<img>` elements.  You can up-vote it here though to get it added for video:  https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/32011258-object-fit-and-object-position-for-all-media-eleme

Comment: Thanks @TheChewy just upvoted!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the way to fix that.

This can be fixed with css by following code:

```
background-size: cover;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
```

And yes, it acts like a `object-fit` and works for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

A little crude, and deals only with 16:9 aspect ratio videos, but I used this...

```
function fill() {
    if (9 * $( window ).width() > 16 * $( window ).height()) {
        $('video').css('width', '100%');
        $('video').css('height', '');
    } else {
        $('video').css('width', '');
        $('video').css('height', '100%');
    }
}
function fit() {
    if (9 * $( window ).width() < 16 * $( window ).height()) {
        $('video').css('width', '100%');
        $('video').css('height', '');
    } else {
        $('video').css('width', '');
        $('video').css('height', '100%');
    }
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
    fit();
    $( window ).on('resize', function() {
        fit();
    });
});
```

I guess it's a good place to start.